# Which tags are watched by SE Staff on per site metas?

Tags: support, tags

I've had a recent post on the meta of the site I'm on which, arguably on topic for us, certainly needs [someone with greater insight into the system to take a look](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12898/my-cross-site-auto-login-does-not-work-where-do-i-look-to-fix-it).

While I'm aware that *some* tags on site metas are watched by CMs and Devs, is there a list we can refer to of such tags? It might be handy for mods to retag if needed

Comment: In addition to the four required tags I think [design] is also monitored, but not being employee I can only go on what I've gathered over the years.

Comment: My bet is on bugs and feature requests but best is to just stalk them in a chatroom for 6 to 8 weeks

Comment: heh. Its one of those things we kinda take for granted - then realise we actually need to know. 4 required tags... sounds like a lot, even if metas are not that busy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not true for this *specific* situation for broader system issues - the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag [will get attention via the CM team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344586/our-commitment-to-responding-to-meta-and-moderators)

You'll need to get a Mod to do it - but for now, that's as close to a list of "monitored tags" as we have.