# Should the disposition of a flag to add the [status-review] tag match the final action on the post?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, moderator-tags, helpful-flags

In a recent [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344586/336163) covering the future of the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag, JNat ♦ mentioned,

> Users may flag a post that they believe should be tagged [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) and the moderators or staff will decide whether to add the tag.

If a diamond moderator sees one of these flags and decides not to add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag, should the flag be *declined* or should the flag be marked *helpful* or at least *disputed* if the flag was not complete noise? In other words, if the moderator is thinking about responding, "**Thanks for flagging this - it was important that I got the opportunity to review it, but in the end I have decided not to add the [status-review] tag.**", should they also mark the flag *declined*, or would that only be called for in the case of *obvious* flag noise or abuse (e.g. raising a "*plz add [status-review] kthx*" flag on spam, rants, or blatantly off-topic questions)?

Comment: Custom moderator flags cannot be marked disputed. That status only occurs automatically in certain cases.

Comment: There's also an avenue for abuse in mass-flagging of posts. Someone raises dozens of these, I'm probably not going to be happy about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some guidance about handling flags can be found [in this rather old newsletter](https://stackmod.blog/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/):

> **Flags should be closed as `[helpful]` under most circumstances.** If you feel strongly that a question was flagged in bad faith, it is okay to mark it `[declined]`. But try to err on the side of clearing as `[helpful]` whenever the user is trying to be genuinely helpful, *even if you do not necessarily act on the flag*...

IMHO that guidance applies here as well; at the very least, in my position as ♦ moderator on Ask Different and Chess Stack Exchange, I personally adhere to this guidance in general. I see no reason to deviate from it when handling requests for applying the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag.