# What recourse do I have if I believe an SO employee has unfairly declined a feature request?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team

I made a feature request a while back, and a Staff-marked user (who is a paid employee, as I understand correctly) marked it status-declined before the community had voted much on it (must have been -1 or 0), and wrote an answer stating his/her reasons. I am deliberately not providing a link, since I don't want to focus on that instance (the community eventually voted strongly against the proposal and in favor of the staff member's reason; though I believe they were all completely incorrect, I understand they're entitled to their opinion). But I hope you will take my word for it that this was not one of those perpetually suggested poor ideas which everybody comes to Meta to whine about: it was not remotely similar to anything previously suggested (no research or comments suggested that), and it was not a blatant violation of SE philosophy (staff marked it declined because it's supposedly not worth the effort to program into the system).

The staff member did not appear to have consulted other SE employees (his/her response was written within 10 minutes of my proposal, so there wasn't sufficient time for him/her to have thoroughly read my proposal, thought it through, sent it to other employees to ensure at least some consensus, and then written the answer). Are staff members allowed to single-handedly mark stuff that way? What would have happened if other staff members who came by a few minutes later felt that the feature was worth implementing? Or if the community had eventually voted in favor of implementing the feature?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344586/our-commitment-to-responding-to-meta-and-moderators ?  If there's an appeal avenue available, then I would expect to find it mentioned there.

Comment: Edit your proposal with better arguments taking into consideration all concerns expressed in the comments/answers and any previous itterations of the request made by other users.

Answer (score 13):

Allowed?  Of course they're allowed.  What would forbid them?  Stack Exchange runs the site.  They control the budget that pays the salary of the software developers that would implement any proposed features.  While the community plays an important part, it's only reasonable to expect that the company will have ultimate control over their software development money and set priorities for where they spend it.  If they know they're not going to implement it, I'd prefer to see them communicate the results of their decision (by setting a status-declined flag) if they know that they're not going to implement it, rather than just privately make the decision and not let us know.

I don't see what's unfair on the surface about declining a feature request.  Unfair by whose criteria?  For all I know, maybe your feature request is something that has already been considered at length and rejected for perfectly reasonable reasons.  I'm not trying to rule out the possibility that there could exist some set of circumstances that would make a rapid decision unfair, but without any details, I don't see that there's any basis or evidence for concluding that this decision was unfair -- and it seems it would take take an extraordinary set of circumstances for that to be the case.

It's probably hard to give you more useful feedback or help you understand plausible rationales for the decision, without knowing the specifics of the particular feedback request.

Comment: Yep, I agree. The community can ask but really cannot dictate things. If I were to ask for a new feature (deliberately weird) "I want to be able to time travel" then despite any support I might get, SE can just refuse to implement this citing the impossibility from physics standpoint. They totally can do that. OP might not have asked for the *physically* impossible but there are still limits to what SE can and will commit to. That's normal - there aren't infinite resources at their disposal.